# SWIG %extend variables

Tags: lua, swig

In most cases Im happy by the way SWIG is handling data, however Im facing an issue and cannot find an answer in the documentation.

First of all Im using SWIG with Lua and have the following structures wrapped:

```
typedef struct 
{ 
    %mutable; 
        float x,y,z; 
    ...
    ...

} Vector3; 


typedef struct 
{
    ...
    ...

    %immutable; 
        Vector3 gravity; 

    ...
    ...

    %extend 
    { 
        void SetGravity(Vector3 gravity) 
        { 
            WorldSetGravity($self,gravity); 
        } 
    }; 
} World;
```

As you can see the gravity XYZ can be affected by calling the `SetGravity` function, and it work great.

However, in order to be more intuitive and easier to use, I would like to give the opportunity to the user to set component (XY or Z) independently like:

```
world.gravity.x=-10;
```

But I need to call in the background `SetGravity` in order to be able to send the proper value to the physics engine (which is not exposed to Lua).

I would like to know if there’s a way to `%extend` variables which will allow me to call `SetGravity` when the `world.gravity.xy or z` is called?

Or be able to implement my own version of the wrap function for each component like: `_wrap_World_gravity_set_x` which will allot me to call `SetGravity` in the background.

Comment: If you want `world.gravity.x` to be mutable then why is `world.gravity` marked immutable? If an object is marked immutable then you should not design hacks that make parts of it mutable. Something is not right, perhaps describe how you want to use gravity and constraints.

Comment: One point to note: it's easier to answer questions like this if you show the minimal, yet still complete amount of code needed to illustrate the question. As it stands when I started answering I had to re-invent stuff you've presumably already got. In general you'll get more and better answers if you stick to that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it's worth noting that this problem is harder than simply making a "virtual" member variable using `%extend` that automatically calls an extra function when someone modifies it. This is because you want the fact that it's a member of another class to alter the behaviour.

I can see several fundamental approaches you could take to get this behaviour:

1. Inject some extra code in the target scripting language to hook the set
2. Inject some extra stuff in the SWIG interface to transparently convert the `Vector3` inside `World` to something that still looks and feels the same, but has the behaviour you want under the hood.
3. Inject some extra code into the memberin typemap for `Vector3` that checks the context it's being called from and modifies the behaviour accordingly.

Of these #2 is my preferred solution because #1 is language specific (and I don't know Lua well enough to do it!) and #3 feels dirty from a software engineering perspective.

To implement #2 I did the following:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

typedef struct 
{ 
    %mutable; 
    float x,y,z; 
} Vector3; 

%nodefaultctor Vector3Gravity;

%{
// Inside C this is just a typedef!
typedef Vector3 Vector3Gravity;
// But we have magic for sets/gets now:
#define MEMBER_VAR(ct,vt,rt,n)                                      \
  SWIGINTERN void ct##_##n##_set(ct *self, const vt val) {          \
    self->n = val;                                                  \
    /* Need to find a way to lookup world here */                   \
    WorldSetGravity(world, self);                                   \
  }                                                                 \
  SWIGINTERN vt ct##_##n##_get(const ct *self) { return self->n; }

 MEMBER_VAR(Vector3Gravity, float, Vector3, x)
 MEMBER_VAR(Vector3Gravity, float, Vector3, y)
 MEMBER_VAR(Vector3Gravity, float, Vector3, z)
%}

// Inside SWIG Vector3Gravity is a distinct type:
typedef struct
{
    %mutable; 
    %extend {
      float x,y,z;  
    }
} Vector3Gravity;


%typemap(memberin,noblock=1) Vector3Gravity gravity %{
  $1 = *((const Vector3*)$input);
  WorldSetGravity($self, $1); // This gets expanded to automatically make this call
%}

typedef struct 
{
  // This is a blatant lie!
  Vector3Gravity gravity; 
} World;
```

Essentially we're lying and claiming that the `gravity` member of world is a "special" type, whereas really it's just a `Vector3`. Our special type has two distinct features. Firstly sets/gets on its members are implemented a C code by us. Secondly when we set this member we automatically make an extra call rather than just pass the values in.

There are two things possibly missing from this example that you might want:

1. Transparent conversion from `Vector3Gravity` to `Vector3`. (As it stands anything other than the set for gravity will refuse to accept `Vector3Gravity` instances). You can make that transparent by using the overload resolution mechanisms of SWIG/Lua if needed.
2. Inside the setters for `Vector3Gravity` we don't know which world this gravity belongs to.

   We could solve that in several ways, the simplest being to implicitly set a static pointer every time we create a `Vector3Gravity`. This would make sense if there only ever is one world.

   Another approach would be to use a global map of `Vector3Gravity` instances to worlds that gets maintained automatically.

   Finally, instead of using a `typedef` for the `Vector3Gravity` type we could make it a real distinct type, with a compatible layout, but add a pointer to the `World` it came from. That's more work though.

Comment: Humm... At some point I was toying with something similar, by creating a "fake" Gravity structure which hold the XYZ and %extend it so when each component is called SetGravity is trigger. It work, but the problem is that gravity is not a Vector3 anymore and cannot use any of the Vector3 functions. Is there a way to keep gravity a Vector3 and only %extend the XYZ set methods to trigger SetGravity? Of course in the case of gravity, it won't make much sense but, in the case of ie: Object.location.xyz, which would call ie: ObjectSetTransform it would...

Comment: So you want a mechanism by which all vectors can be associated with some other function on changes. I'll have to have a think about that some more. What I'd do would be to make vectors immutable (you change then by creating new ones always) and then use the memberin part of my example to hook modifications to the variables in the right places.

Comment: @Flexo: Im having pretty much the same issue as this user. Would you mind posting an example of your last approach (the one you have to think about some more ;))

Comment: @McBob do you use a C or C++ for this and is it still targeting lua or another language?

Comment: Im using C and yes Im targeting Lua as well.